# How to apply Wick's theorem in 2nd quantization for Spin Density Operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, wick-theorem

I am trying to work out a correlation function consisting of two spin density operators. Once I rewrite everything in 2nd quantized form, I am unsure of how to apply wicks theorem because the paul matrix spins are sandwiched between creation/annihilation operators.

If it is a regular density operator I have no problem doing this, since I don't have the Pauli spin vectors to deal with.

Hope my problem clear... any suggestions? Specifically, how to deal with the sandwiched Pauli terms

Comment: The problem is not clear to me. Always tough to describe equations with words...